# Upload word document

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I need to extract text from the word document uploaded by the user. I got the [code](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/java/reading-word-document-in-java) to extract words from a document located on my m/c. But my requirement is to allow users to upload their own document using the upload button & read that document(I dont need to save that document). Can you please suggest me how to go about this? I need to know what all need to happen after clicking the upload button.

Comment: which upload button? Are you using any MVC framework?

Comment: You can find related questions and answers by [searching for related tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+upload+file).

Comment: I am using servlets & the upload button would look like <p>
Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user uploads their file, grab the associated `InputStream` and store it to a variable, like `inputStream`.  Then just take the example code, and replace this line:

```
fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(filesname));
```

...with something like:

```
fs = new POIFSFileSystem(inputStream);
```

Should be simple enough, assuming that you already have a `Servlet` in place to handle the upload.

Edit:

Here are the basics of how the servlet could work, assuming that you are using [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) to parse the upload:

```
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Create a factory for disk-based file items
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        // Parse the request
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

        //this assumes that the uploaded file is the only thing submitted by the form
        //if not you need to iterate the list and find it
        FileItem wordFile = items.get(0);

        //get a stream that can be used to read the uploaded file
        InputStream inputStream = wordFile.getInputStream();

        //and the rest you already know...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Can you please tell me how to grab the InputStream of the file uploaded in my servlet. Thank you!

Comment: I search InputStream on the net & got something like this `InputStream input = new FileInputStream("c:\\data\\input-text.txt");` This too read file from a fixed location

Comment: @dazzle - I've updated the post with some example code, hope that helps.